# StaleElementReferenceException in python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to count how many time "Load More Reviews" option is clicked from [this site](https://www.justdial.com/Delhi/S-K-Premium-Par-Hari-Nagar/011PXX11-XX11-131128122154-B8G6_BZDET). But I am getting the following error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Here is my python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=options)
url = "https://www.justdial.com/Delhi/S-K-Premium-Par-Hari-Nagar/011PXX11-XX11-131128122154-B8G6_BZDET"
driver.get(url)
pop_up = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="best_deal_detail_div"]/section/span')))
pop_up.click() # For disable pop-up
count = 0
while True:
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
  EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Load More Reviews..']")))
  element.click()
  count = count + 1
  print(count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
  count = 0
while True:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Load More Reviews..']"))).click()
        count = count + 1
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        pass
    except TimeoutException:
        break
print(count)
```

**Issue:**  As per your code you are waiting for **Load More Reviews** button to be clickable, now once its clicked and even before page has finished loading its detecting if button is there and clickable, but when its try to click , by that time page is still in process of refresing / loading more reviews. As a result `HTML DOM` is disrupted/refreshed and `stale element exception` comes.

**Also as there is no** `break` condition in your code, i have added one. If there is no Load More Reviews button on page. It will break out of loop.

Comment: Also there is no break condition in your code, so it will keep runnig. As you have put while as True. Please check updated one for break.